# How to Minus no of vacancy once student is assigned to company?

Tags: php, mysql, count

Scenario : Students are assigned to companies based on departments. Each company has different number of vacancy. Eg company A's no of vacancy is 4. The companies assigned to students are chosen by the Admin from a drop down list.

Problem : How to subtract 1 once a student is assigned to company A whose vacancy is 4. Meaning it should show as 3 once student is assigned.

```
      <?php
$result3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT job_title, no_of_vacancy FROM job_details WHERE jobscope = 'Information Technology' ORDER BY `job_title` ASC;");
?>
<table cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Vacancy</th>
  </tr>
<?php
  while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row3['job_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgColor=white>" . $row3['no_of_vacancy'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
</table>
<?php
$result5 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT company FROM student_details WHERE jobscope1 = 'Information Technology';");
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5);
$assigned = $row5['company'];  

if(isset($_POST['ddl']))
        {
            foreach($_POST['ddl'] as $index => $val2 ) 
            {
            $result4 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `job_details` SET `no_of_vacancy`= `no_of_vacancy` - 1 
                      WHERE `job_title` = '" . $val2 . "';");

            }
        } 



}
?>
```

After suggested edit :

Before submitting the drop down options

```
Company Name           |Vacancy  
__________________________________
Commonwealth  Pte Ltd  | 3
Delloitte              | 1
Oak 3 Films Pte Ltd    | 3
Promedia Directories   | 2
```

After submitting drop down options

eg

I choose 2 students to be assigned to *commonwealth*
1 student to be assigned to *Deloitte*
2 students to be assigned to *Oak*
1 student to be assigned to *Promedia*

So the CORRECT form show should this

```
Company Name           |Vacancy  
__________________________________
Commonwealth  Pte Ltd  | 1
Delloitte              | 0
Oak 3 Films Pte Ltd    | 1
Promedia Directories   | 1
```

However this shows

```
Company Name           |Vacancy  
__________________________________
Commonwealth  Pte Ltd  | 1
Delloitte              | 0
Oak 3 Films Pte Ltd    | 3
Promedia Directories   | 2
```

What is wrong?? Only the top tow rows is affected. Why isnt the 3rd and last row affected too?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the backticks (`) around your field names.

So,

```
UPDATE `job_details` 
              SET `no_of_vacancy`= `no_of_vacancy` - 1 
              WHERE `jobscope` = 'Information Technology' 
              AND `job_title` = '" . $assigned . "';
```

Becomes:

```
UPDATE job_details 
              SET no_of_vacancy= no_of_vacancy - 1 
              WHERE jobscope = 'Information Technology' 
              AND job_title = '" . $assigned . "';
```

That way, mysql knows you are referring to a field (no_of_vacancy) and subtracting 1 from its current value.

Backticks allow you to reference field names that are identical to reserved mysql words. For example, a table named `where`.

Comment: i edited the necessary but it only minus of the values from one of the fields of no_of_vacancy..why doesnt it show the same for the rest of the fields? @Groovepig

Comment: I'm not certain of your entire table structure, but maybe the update is not applying to all of the rows because WHERE jobscope = 'Information Technology' does not apply to them?  What is your complete UPDATE query you are running?

Comment: Also, it looks like $assigned is being set to a company name, yes?  Then in your WHERE clause, you have: AND `job_title` = '" . $assigned . "';  which is a job_title, presumably.  Not sure if that's causing the issue.

Comment: I have updated my codes to use the foreach function. however, nothing is reflected.